# AutoHotKey - Resizing Windows

Tags: resize, autohotkey

I currently have a HTPC connected to a plasma in my living room, and I've had a few issues with image retention.  While browsing the web, etc. for an extended period of time I'll run into the issue.  However, it looks like it should be relatively easy to set up a script with AutoHotKey to resize the window automatically on a timer.  Could anyone help me get started on a script to accomplish this task? (Also open to any other ideas)

Thanks!

Comment: Resizing multiple windows or just one particular window? Moving it too, or just making it bigger/smaller?

Answer (score 6):

I created a script quite a while ago that "normalizes" windows, i.e. resizes, moves, and performs other actions to make a window confirm to my personal preference.

Whenever a window displays for the first time, it is normalized. If it is closed and re-opened, it is normalized again.

Below is a functioning version of the script and should satisfy the requirements from the original question.

The version I use is much more complicated because it has many more features, e.g. it supports multiple monitors and resizes windows while taking into account the height of the Windows task bar. I use the script to make open/save dialogs bigger (they are too small by default). I also use it to auto-login to some websites and applications.

```
; This script "normalizes" windows, i.e. resizes, moves, and performs other
; actions to make a window confirm to my personal preference.

SetTitleMatchMode, 2

; Go into an infinite loop
loop
{
    ; Pause so other apps can execute. 250 milliseconds seems to work well.
    Sleep, 250

    ; If hotkeys are suspended for this script, then suspend all functionality
    if A_IsSuspended
        continue

    ; We will build a unique window name using the window title and window handle.
    ; Store each unique name in an array.
    WinGet, HWND, ID, A
    WinGetTitle, WindowTitle, A
    WinGetClass, WindowClass, A

    ; Remember the previous window we processed
    WindowTitleCleanPrevious := WindowTitleClean

    ; Only normalize windows that we haven't seen before.
    ; If we haven't already normalized the window, we do
    ; the normalize, then set a flag so we don't normalize the same window again.

    ; Strip out all chars that may be invalid in an AHK variable name.
    WindowTitleCleanTemp := StringRemoveAllNonAlphaNum(WindowTitle)
    ; Variable names can be at most 254 chars, so truncate to less than that.
    StringLeft, WindowTitleClean, WindowTitleCleanTemp, 230

    ; Process the window if:
    ; (1) It wasn't previously processed (i.e. not in our window-name list named WinList)
    ; (2) And we aren't sitting on the same window during each loop.
    if (WinList%HWND%%WindowTitleClean% != 1 and WindowTitleClean != WindowTitleCleanPrevious)
    {
        ; Get the window's position and size
        WinGetPos, WinX, WinY, WinWidth, WinHeight, A

        ; Is this an MS Word window?
        if (WindowClass == "OpusApp")
        {
            ; Center the window and resize so it is 80% of the monitor width and 90% of height.
            WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(WinWidth/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(WinHeight/2), A_ScreenWidth * .8, A_ScreenHeight * .9
        }
        ; Is this the Calculator window?
        else if (WindowClass == "SciCalc")
        {
            ; Center the window
            WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(WinWidth/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(WinHeight/2) 
        }

        ; Set a flag indicating this window has been processed so it is
        ; not processed again.
        WinList%HWND%%WindowTitleClean% = 1
    }
}


; --- Win+F5 will Reload this script ---
~#F5::Reload

; --- Win+Escape will Pause this script ---
~#Escape::Suspend, Toggle

; --- Win+Alt+Escape will Exit this script ---
; Close this script
~#!Escape::ExitApp



; ===========================================================================
; Removes all non-alphabetic and non-numeric characters from the given
; string.  The resulting string is returned.
; ===========================================================================
StringRemoveAllNonAlphaNum(SourceString)
{
    StringSplit, SplitSourceString, SourceString

    OutputString =
    Loop, %SplitSourceString0%
    {
        Char := SplitSourceString%A_Index%
        if (Char >= "a") and (Char <= "z")
            OutputString := OutputString Char
        else if (Char >= "0") and (Char <= "9")
            OutputString := OutputString Char
    }

    return OutputString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same problem. Here is a script that opens and [centers](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) the Windows calculator based of your current screen size. I am still figuring everything out, but maybe this will get you started.

```
;This script opens and centers the calculator on your screen.
#NoTrayIcon
Run, calc.exe
WinWait, Calculator
WinGetPos,,, Width, Height, %WinTitle%
WinMove, %WinTitle%,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(Width/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize and snap the window using the below short cuts.

- **Windows Key + Left Arrow** = Window snaps to left side of the screen
- **Windows Key + Right Arrow** = Window snaps to right side of the screen
- **Windows Key + Up Arrow** = Window snaps to upper side of the screen
- **Windows Key + Down Arrow** = Window snaps to lower side of the screen
- **Windows Key + Up & Left Arrow** = Window snaps to upper left corner of the screen
- **Windows Key + Up & Right Arrow** = Window snaps to upper right corner of the screen